# How to save HSSF rows as String java POI

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-poi

I am trying to filter a spreadsheet based on a key word. I want to then store the rows in a multidimensional string array (cell values and rows). I can't quite seem to get each cell to be a separate element. All the cells in all the arrays are being added to one array:

Here is the code:

```
////Adding each filtered row to an ArrayList

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook      workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fis);
        HSSFSheet         sheet    = workBook.getSheetAt (0);

        List<HSSFRow> filteredRows = new ArrayList<HSSFRow>();
        ArrayList<List<HSSFRow>> TwoD = new ArrayList<List<HSSFRow>>();
        Iterator<Row> rows= sheet.rowIterator(); 
        while (rows.hasNext ()){
        HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next ();  
        Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator (); 
         while (cells.hasNext ()){
             HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next (); 
              if (cell.toString().contains("GHH")) {
                  filteredRows.add(row);
                }
        }
         }

///////  Now iterating through the filteredRows arrayList and turn it into multidimensional String array

        ArrayList<String> in =new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<List<String>> out = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        for (HSSFRow n:filteredRows){

            Iterator<Cell> cells = n.cellIterator (); 
             while (cells.hasNext ()){
                 HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next (); 
                 in.add(cell.toString());

             }
             out.add(in);
        }

        workBook.close();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you move the `in` variable to be created inside your per-row for loop?

Comment: Aha. Yes. Add as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not resetting the `in` array list between rows

You either need to change it to be something like:

```
ArrayList<List<String>> out = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (HSSFRow n:filteredRows){
    ArrayList<String> in =new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Cell cell : n) {
```

And create a new list for holding your cells each time.

Note - this code won't work:

```
ArrayList<String> in =new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<List<String>> out = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (HSSFRow n:filteredRows){
    for (Cell cell : n) {
       // Logic here
    }
    out.add(in);
    in.clear();
}
```

Because you're adding the same object each time, you'll just end up with `out` containing multiple copies of the last row at the end! As you're keeping the references to the arrays, they need to be separate objects